# Date difference on same column

Tags: sql

I have a table with ID and datelastupdated columns , i need get the count for the difference in the date for 12,24,36 months

```
ID    Datelastupdate
1012    1/1/2016
1012    1/2/2017
1012    1/7/2014
2014    1/1/2015
2014    1/1/2016
3071    2/2/2017
3071    2/2/2015
```

Output:

```
 Count  Monthsdiff
    1   12
    1   24
    1   >24
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Date and time functions can be database specific.

Comment: What was your approach so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using two levels of aggregation.  Using ANSI SQL date functions:

```
select which, count(*)
from (select id,
             (case when max(Datelastupdate) <= min(Datelastupdate) + interval '12 month'
                   then '12'
                   when max(Datelastupdate) <= min(Datelastupdate) + interval '24 month'
                   then '24'
                   when max(Datelastupdate) <= min(Datelastupdate) + interval '12 month'
                   else '24+'
              end) as which
      from t
      group by id
     ) t
group by which;
```